# Load XML in php

Tags: php, xml, dom, foreach

I have a SimpleXMLElement Object that I want to import with PHP.
But it only loop through the first row in the XML file.
I also want to show the specific columm with $item->columm1 instead of show the whole row whith all it's values  .

```
$url = 'file.xml';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($sxml->Departure->attributes() as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

EDIT: Here is the output, notice that I have edit the orginal values with text1, text2.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[Departure] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => text1 [type] => text2 [stop] => text3 [time] => text4 [date] => text4 [direction] => text5 )
```

EDIT2: Output->

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(6)     "text1" ["type"]=> string(3) "text2" ["stop"]=> string(12) "text3" ["time"]=> string(5) "text4" ["date"]=> string(8) "text5" ["direction"]=> string(10) "text6" } ["JourneyDetailRef"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["ref"]=> string(125) "text7" } } }
```

EDIT3: Output->

```
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(6) "text1" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "text2" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(12) "text3" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "text4" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(8) "text5" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(10) "text6" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$item has become the object. When you want to loop over the item, make sure you tell what part of the item you want to echo out to the screen.

For example:

```
$url = 'file.xml';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);

//foreach loop
foreach($sxml->Departure as $item){
    //vardump
    var_dump($item);

    //construct next piece of code
    foreach($item->attributes() as $key => $piece){
         echo $key.' = '.$piece;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the XML data?

Comment: @user1273409 Try running `print_r($sxml);` or `var_export($sxml);` and looking at the structure of the object.  From there you should be able to discern callable functions.  Another option could be that once inside the `foreach` do this: `die(var_export($item, true));`.  That will halt execution and print the structure of `$item`.  From *there* you should be able to see what `$item` is and figure out if you're at the right place in the XML hierarchy and what to call.

Comment: @Tim I have added the output at the top.

Comment: Have you tried debugging each step of the foreach loop, so you can see the output? I put an example in the answer.

Comment: That looks better. But Is it possible to show only one Attribute with a variable. So I could change the order of the them. $piece->name and $piece->type like mysql with $row